# Can't create a MySQL View

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I run this SQL code to create a view but this doesn't work :

```
Create VIEW as
    select
        c.ID_CAPTEUR as ID_CAPTEUR,
        d.ID_CAPTURE as ID_CAPTURE,
        d.VALEUR_CAPTURE as valeur,
        d.DATE_CAPTURE,
        t.INTITULE_TYPE_CAPTURE as TYPE_CAPTURE,
        z.INTITULE_ZONE as zone,
        r.INTITULE_REGION as region
    from CAPTEUR c, CAPTURE d, TYPECAPTURE t, ZONE z, REGION r
    where c.ID_CAPTEUR=d.ID_CAPTEUR
          and d.ID_TYPE_CAPTURE=t.ID_TYPE_CAPTURE
          and c.ID_ZONE = z.ID_ZONE
          and z.ID_REGION = r.ID_REGION
```

I get this error :

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as select c.ID_CAPTEUR as ID_CAPTEUR , d.ID_CAPTURE as ID_CAPTURE , d.VALEUR_CAP' at line 1
```

Comment: Think, how will you refer to this view later?

Comment: you need to give a view name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the syntax of the [`CREATE VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) statement:

```
CREATE
[OR REPLACE]
[ALGORITHM = {UNDEFINED | MERGE | TEMPTABLE}]
[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
[SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }]
VIEW view_name [(column_list)]
AS select_statement
[WITH [CASCADED | LOCAL] CHECK OPTION]
```

As you can see, your query is missing the `view_name` parameter (parameters between `[` and `]` are optionnal, which is not the case of `view_name`).